# Unable to add contents over my background image in java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am creating a profile page. At the left, I have added a jlabel containing a background image to my jpanel. Now over this panel, I want to add another jlabel for the icon. However, it is not showing up. Please help me.

P.s: This is only part of the code

```
 public CustomerProfile()
 {
    super("Customer Profile");
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    //PROFILE DETAILS JPANEL
    jpProfile = new JPanel();
    add(jpProfile, BorderLayout.WEST);

    //BACKGROUND IMAGE OF THE PROFILE JPANEL
    ImageIcon background_img = new ImageIcon("background.jpg");
    Image img = background_img.getImage();
    Image tempImg = img.getScaledInstance(350, 600, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
    background_img = new ImageIcon(tempImg);
    background = new JLabel("",background_img,JLabel.CENTER);
    jpProfile.add(background);

    //PROFILE ICON
    ImageIcon profImg = new ImageIcon("female.png");
    jlProfileIcon = new JLabel();
    jlProfileIcon.setIcon(profImg);

    //ADDING PROFILE ICON TO JPANEL
    jpProfileIcon = new JPanel();
    jpProfileIcon.add(jlProfileIcon);

    //jpProfile.setOpaque(false);
    //jpProfileIcon.setOpaque(false);
    jpProfileIcon.add(jlProfileIcon);
    background.add(jpProfileIcon);




  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default only a JPanel uses a layout manager.

The JLabel does not use a layout manager so the size/location of any component added to the label is not changed. The default size of a component is (0, 0) so there is nothing to paint.

Try:

```
background = new JLabel("",background_img,JLabel.CENTER);
background.setLayout( new BorderLayout() ); // added
…
background.add(jlProfileIcon);
```

The following code is not needed:

```
//jpProfileIcon = new JPanel();
//jpProfileIcon.add(jlProfileIcon);
```

That is you don't need to create a JPanel, just to add the label to it.

A better option is to paint the background image onto a panel and then you can just add your label normally to the panel. See: [Background Panel](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/12/background-panel/) for a class that implements this functionality.

Comment: i did not understand about what you said for the jlabel layout manager part.

Comment: u told me that a jlabel does not use a layout manager. Then why did u set the layout for background?

Comment: Correct, which is why you need to set one, if you want to add a component to the label.

Comment: @camikr Thanks a ton